# Comparing all codes in different folders?

Tags: python, notepad++

I know how to compare two files' codes. Just open the two codes in notepad++ and Plugins->Compare

But how can I compare all codes in different folders when there are simply too many files?

For example, let's say in my PC there are two folders C:/A and C:/B

And these two folders have the same files a.py and b.py

I want to compare a.py in C:/A and a.py in C:/B, 
and compare b.py in C:/A and b.py in C:/B.

Comment: No idea why this would be off topic, totally important and relevant

Comment: WinMerge is perfect here. It is opensource and completely free to use.
https://winmerge.org/?lang=en

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php) to compare file sets. There are plenty of other tools out there that will do this too.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thanks to you, I could also find out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools and this will help a lot of people who come to visit this page!

Comment: Note that Beyond Compare free version is 30 days trail